# Third-order autonomous ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What must be true of $f:R\rightarrow R$ for it to satisfy $3f'(x)^2f''(x)-3f(x)f''(x)^2+f(x)f'(x)f'''(x)=0$?
Such functions would constitute the entire class of "constant quantity pass-through" demand curves. Clearly $f(x)=a-bx$ works. Are there other decreasing functions that are not linear that also work?

Comment: Interesting thing is $(f(x)f'(x)f''(x))'=(f'(x))^{2}f''(x)+f(x)(f''(x))^2+f(x)f'(x)f'''(x)$

Answer (score 0):

let me try. let $$u = y', v = y''.$$ with this we can re write the equation $ 3f'(x)^2f''(x)-3f(x)f''(x)^2+f(x)f'(x)f'''(x)=0$ as 
$$\begin{align} 0 &= 3u^2v-3yv^2+yuv'\\yuv' &= 3yv^2-3u^2v\\
\frac {v'}{v^2} + \frac{3u} y\frac1v &= \frac3u\\
y^3\left(\frac1v\right)'+3y^2y'\left(\frac1v\right)&=\frac{3y^3}u\\
\left(\frac{y^3}v\right)' &=\frac{3y^3}u
\end{align}$$

we can try a  particular solution by setting $$ \left(\frac{y^3}v\right)' =\frac{3y^3}u = \frac6k \tag 1$$ where $k$ is an arbitrary  constant. solving $$k = \frac{2u}{y^3}=\frac{2y'}{y^3}=2y^{-3}\frac{dy}{dx} \to y^{-2}= c-kx$$ that is $$ y = \left(c-kx\right)^{-1/2},y' = u = \frac k2 y^3, v = u' = \frac {3k}2y^2\frac k2y^3=\frac{3k^2}4y^5$$

we need $$ \left(\frac{y^3}v\right)' = \frac 6k\to \frac6k=\frac{4}{3k^2}\left(y^{-2}\right)'= \frac{4}{3k^2}(-2)y^{-3}u= -\frac4{3k}$$

unfortunately, this does not work.